# In a dnn website, body image loaded first.Is it possible to load the image after the page is loaded

Tags: dotnetnuke

In a **DNN** website, body image loaded first. 
Is it possible to load the image at the end of the page load?

Answer (score 0):

here is another question that answers this

[Use Javascript to load some images last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230916/use-javascript-to-load-some-images-last)

Remember this will be better in a skin - dont use the body Background in the Appearance section of the site settings