# Speed up website / VPS

Tags: server

I have a website https://www.voclr.it

How can I speed it up? it has 229 requests and its on a GoDaddy VPS, it takes 8s per page to load!

The website is built with Wordpress/Bootstrap.

Comment: This question will get slaughtered! Who knows what's causing it to be slow. What's on the pages. Open up Chrome DevTools and look to see what's taking so long to load. The response from the server? The rendering once it's in the browser? Too many possible answers.

Comment: I'm just looking for advice, i test other sites and they load a lot quicker.

Comment: Describing the problem accurately would *way* beyond the scope of a question here. Describing how to isolate and resolve the faults would fill a book. (But I can tell you that most of the problems are in the awful page design, not serverside). Go read some good books on web page optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at any serverside processing you do and ensure it is well written - that can be one potential bottleneck.

Another thing would be that there is actually a lot of content on the page so consider loading some of it via ajax requests - the actual page wouldn't appear faster but you can put the most important bits of it there first and then load extra bits further down via ajax (the point is that the user gets to the page quicker).

Finally, I would suggest moving all your javascript (as in both the loading external files and the scripts defined on that page) to the bottom of the page - loading a lot of javascript has been a major cause of slowing down page loads for me previously.

Having said all that, you need to do some profiling of your code to determine specific bottlenecks. [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) - but now you have the site working it is time to do it!

**Viewing how long resources take to load**

Open Chrome and then right-click on whatever your default page is and click "inspect element". In the tabs above the code open "Network" and then go to your page. You can see that the page itself takes about 4s and then the javascript files are taking ~2s each as well.

**Loading images**

Also consider loading your images after the main page is loaded by following the [updated answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230916/use-javascript-to-load-some-images-last)

Comment: @BradHouston You're welcome :) I would definitely suggest using devtools of a browser to examine which part may be slowing it down though - Firefox or Chrome are both quite good for this.

Comment: Majority of issues are not serverside. Premature optimization? It's long overdue in this case.